# get Bitmap from SD card using Glide android

Tags: android, android-glide

I am trying to fetch Bitmap of image stored on Sd card using Glide but it is not working for me.

```
Bitmap bitmapByGlide = Glide.with(this).load(imagePath).asBitmap().into(100, 100).get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
   Glide.with(this)
        .load(Uri.fromFile(new File(url)))
        .asBitmap()
        .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
             bitmapByGlide = resource;
            }
        });
```

(use Uri.formFile() is trick of this)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 Glide.with(this)
            .load(url)
            .asBitmap()
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private SimpleTarget target = new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {  
    @Override
    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
        // do something with the bitmap
        // for demonstration purposes, let's just set it to an ImageView
        imageView1.setImageBitmap( bitmap );
    }
};

private void loadImageSimpleTarget() {  
    Glide
        .with( context ) // could be an issue!
        .load( eatFoodyImages[0] )
        .asBitmap()
        .into( target );
}
```

Source: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-callbacks-simpletarget-and-viewtarget-for-custom-view-classes

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
File b = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150828_174009.jpg");
```

**and**

```
       Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(b).error(R.drawable.empty_pic).placeholder(R.drawable.empty_pic).into(image2);
```